# Synching iPhone with internet calendar (.ics)

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, internet, internet-sharing

Looks like my issue has been around for a while ([iOS 5.0.1 (iPhone 4s) unable to synchronize with Internet Calendar File (ics)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37392/ios-5-0-1-iphone-4s-unable-to-synchronize-with-internet-calendar-file-ics)) — has anyone come up with a fix yet?  I am trying to sync my iPhone calendars with the calendar on my PC that is in .ics format.  The .ics file is located on a home server that allows both me and my wife to see each other’s calendars and its been working great.  Now, I want to be able to see my calendar from my iPhone 4 (with OS 6.1) .. and I’ve tried setting it up with: Settings / Mail, Contacts, Calendars / Add Account… / Other / Add Subscribed Calendar. With every possible configuration I can think of, I get the same response:

> Calendar Subscription — Unable to verify account information

For server name, I’ve tried actual servername, IP address, etc; we do have security on the server but I put in the account name and password … ‘nuthin! Unable to verify. Through the phone's browser, I am able to open up the folder on our server and see the .ics file. The path is

> xxxx.homeserver.com/webcal/nat_calendar.ics.

I've tried sending an invite to myself, opening it in the phone, clicking on the link and I get this error:

> Cannot Subscribe: Could not subscribe to the calendar nat_calendar.ics from myservername.

Seems simple. What am I missing here?
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56651/ios-icalendar-ics-integration/56664#56664 Does it apply to your case?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to my particular issue.  The reason that my iPhone could not subscribe to a published Outlook .ics calendar was because the MIME type of the .ics file was wrong.  As recommended in [this brilliant post by Joe Bradford](http://bradfo.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/ical-ics-subscription-service-with-ipad-and-iphone/), I went into IIS, changed the MIME type from `application/octet-stream` to `text/calendar`, and iPhone could connect and subscribe without further issue. Success!

PS: I did not run into the second issue that Joe chased down, which was having to remove the Byte Order Mark (BOM) from the .ics file via a hexadecimal editor.

Comment: In our case it was an issue in our backend router, we did not handle https request header Accept:text/calendar properly sent by iOS calendar.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you only have to slide the calendar to 'ON' in your exchange settings.
Settings > Email, contacts, > your account > switch Calendars to ON.

simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I usually send my invitations from Thunderbird. I was having the same problem with the ICS files after upgrading my iPhone 4s to iOS 7.

I did some experimenting and found out that if I turn off the "Support Outlook 2000 and Outlook 2002/XP" option in the E-Mail Notification dialog, the ICS file works on the iPhone; however, if that option is turned on, then the iPhone can't open the ICS file.

Note that this worked fine in the latest iOS 6 build (I always had the Outlook option on). So I would say that something is "broken" in iOS 7 regarding Outlook format ICS files.